# Is it possible to specify that a particular JUnit test must not be run in parallel with other JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit

I have JUnit test that uses testing-specific APIs to inject failures by modifying a global read-only variable.

Unfortunately, that means this test cannot safely run in parallel with other tests.

Is there a mechanism by which I can programmatically inform the JUnit TestRunner to never run this particular test in parallel with other tests?

I have looked through the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/package-summary.html) but do not see anything obvious.

Comment: How do you run the tests that they are running in parallel?

Comment: @Progman, https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0-M1/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Comment: As written in the documentation, it looks like you can use annotations like `@Execution` and `@ResourceLock`. What have you found out about these annotations on the different levels (class vs. method) and configurations with your requirement?

Comment: @Progman, I just found the annotations and am looking at them.